# JDBC Transactions behaviour while tomcat redeploying

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, connection-pooling

What happens when I have a number of active JDBC transactions and a redeploy hits the web application?, I searched the Tomcat docs but didn't find anything related.

For example: 30 customers have a shopping cart with items and they save the order at the same time, so a transaction is started, and a redeploy is triggered
What happens? Do the all items get correctly saved? or At time of redeploy all active transactions are discarded? or Tomcat waits the redeploy command till all the transactions are commited?

I'm using Tomcat JDBC Pool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key point to keep in mind is where is the connection pool instantiated?

If you define the connection pool at the `Context` level, then the connection pool is created when the context is created, and *should* be destroyed with the context too.

Redeploying an application in Tomcat requires shutting down the current context and then starting up the replacement context. So in that case I would expect that the behaviour will be determined by the value of [`defaultAutCommit`](http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html) or the effective value of `autoCommit` for each transaction. If `true` then shutting down the resource should commit the transactions. If `false` then, just like with any `InterruptedException` your exception handling path should trigger rollback, or worst case the connection shutdown should rollback the transaction.

What you really want to examine is how Tomcat shuts down an application. I have not looked at the actual code in detail, but my understanding is that first it stops sending requests to the "old context". Then once all the pending responses have completed, the ServletContextListeners get called to notify of shutdown, once they and their Filter and Servlet counterparts are completed, the context is effectively shut down and the resources can be cleaned up. What complicates things, IIRC is that Tomcat does not wait for ever for responses to complete and may start interrupting the handler treads, or just plain switch over to the new context without waiting for the old or to finish tearring down.

I annot remember which container (jetty/tomcat) supports starting up the new context and then switching request handling over only once the new context is ready to give zero downtime switch over... The key issue with that is you need a persistent session store and an applcation that can run on a cluster safely to be able to use such a deployment mode.

In short, your applcation will be shutdown gracefully before the new context starts, so I would expect transactions to either complete or recipe an `InterruptedException` at which point your `try...finally` blocks should kick in

Comment: Also for high availability it is useful to have at least a couple of Tomcat's running on different server nodes (behind an LB or reverse proxy) so that application updates and OS patches can be applied without users experiencing downtime. This way you can also have a "grace period" before unloading the context: make the LB direct all traffic to the other Tomcat, wait for pending requests to be handled, and only then redeploy or shutdown. Session replication is necessary to make this really work.

Comment: @Stephen Connolly I have my connection pool declared in server.xml,  Does it mean that my connection pools will be running even when a redeploy is triggered to an application using it?

Comment: Well if you have declared the connection pool at the server context, then the pool itself is only shut down when the server context is shut down. This makes sense as other applications in the server may also be using that same pool (which is why you put a pool at the server level in the first place). In that case at some point in time either: the transaction will time out if the webapp shutdown is taking too long and hence roll back; or the webapp will complete the transaction with the response and commit.

Comment: @Stephen Connolly, Correct me please: Even when the connection pool is declared at the server context when an application is redeployed and there are transactions running, the result of those transactions are unpredictable either commit ok or rollback, there's no way to predict this behaviour.

Comment: At some point, if your application is taking too long to shut down, tomcat is going to give up waiting and try and interrupt or otherwise force the issue with an uncooperative application. In those cases, the behaviour will be to roll back any dangling transactions. A well written app will never reach that state. Think of it this way, tomcat stops giving the old app new work, wait for the old work to complete... At some point it will either have to give up, or force the admin to restart Tomcat which gives the same problem

Comment: @Stephen Connolly, correct me please: in short, a well written app that shutdowns fast and the connection pool is declared at server.xml, when this application is redeployed and there are transactions running, there will no problem: every transaction will commit ok

Comment: Theory?, Do you that in practice this  behaviour will get a minimum 90% of transactions correctly committed, or I have to do some tecnique like cluster in Tomcat

Comment: Theory, because I have not looked at the code, only going on my knowledge of the spec and as a heavy user of `ServletContextListener`s.